# Regular expression for non-consecutive characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a regular expression that validates the following requirements:

- Simultaneous use of Cyrillic and numbers is possible (without spaces and special characters)
- Simultaneous use of Latin and numbers is possible (without spaces and special characters)
- Simultaneous use of Cyrillic and Latin characters is not possible
- The first letter must be capitalized, cannot be a number
- Sequence length - from 2 to 16 digits inclusive
- It is impossible to use 3 or more identical symbols in a row

I am using the following solution:
`(?:([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}|[А-Я][А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15}))$`

How do I change the regex to match the last requirement?
I use Google Sheets, in which it is impossible to use negative lookahead.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Without negative lookahead I think its impossible to test using regex. Is this some kind of password rule? I am also curious if `А-ЯЁа-яё0-9``gives the correct "ranges" of characters in use - never used Cyrillic ranges.Can you do "out of regex" grouping for the input and check grouplenghts smaller then 3?

Comment: @PatrickArtner is is nickname checking rule for Black Desert Online game.
https://regex101.com/r/AIaRnr/1
```[А-Я][А-ЯЁа-яё0-9]{1,15}``` - can be deleted for testing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

I don't you can do this with a single regex without lookbehinds.

But there are workarounds for the "don't repeat same character 3 times" functionality.

The workarounds could be simpler if RE2 supported backreferences, but [it does not](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). So the resulting rule will be longer.

You may define a column `ValidNoThreeRepeats` like this:

```
=
NOT(
    OR(
        AND(MID(A1;1 ;1)=MID(A1;2 ;1);MID(A1;2 ;1)=MID(A1;3 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;2 ;1)=MID(A1;3 ;1);MID(A1;3 ;1)=MID(A1;4 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;3 ;1)=MID(A1;4 ;1);MID(A1;4 ;1)=MID(A1;5 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;4 ;1)=MID(A1;5 ;1);MID(A1;5 ;1)=MID(A1;6 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;5 ;1)=MID(A1;6 ;1);MID(A1;6 ;1)=MID(A1;7 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;6 ;1)=MID(A1;7 ;1);MID(A1;7 ;1)=MID(A1;8 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;7 ;1)=MID(A1;8 ;1);MID(A1;8 ;1)=MID(A1;9 ;1));
        AND(MID(A1;8 ;1)=MID(A1;9 ;1);MID(A1;9 ;1)=MID(A1;10;1));
        AND(MID(A1;9 ;1)=MID(A1;10;1);MID(A1;10;1)=MID(A1;11;1));
        AND(MID(A1;10;1)=MID(A1;11;1);MID(A1;11;1)=MID(A1;12;1));
        AND(MID(A1;11;1)=MID(A1;12;1);MID(A1;12;1)=MID(A1;13;1));
        AND(MID(A1;12;1)=MID(A1;13;1);MID(A1;13;1)=MID(A1;14;1));
        AND(MID(A1;13;1)=MID(A1;14;1);MID(A1;14;1)=MID(A1;15;1))
    )
)
```

Or in a compacted way like this:

```
=NOT(OR(AND(MID(A1;1 ;1)=MID(A1;2 ;1);MID(A1;2 ;1)=MID(A1;3 ;1));AND(MID(A1;2 ;1)=MID(A1;3 ;1);MID(A1;3 ;1)=MID(A1;4 ;1));AND(MID(A1;3 ;1)=MID(A1;4 ;1);MID(A1;4 ;1)=MID(A1;5 ;1));AND(MID(A1;4 ;1)=MID(A1;5 ;1);MID(A1;5 ;1)=MID(A1;6 ;1));AND(MID(A1;5 ;1)=MID(A1;6 ;1);MID(A1;6 ;1)=MID(A1;7 ;1));AND(MID(A1;6 ;1)=MID(A1;7 ;1);MID(A1;7 ;1)=MID(A1;8 ;1));AND(MID(A1;7 ;1)=MID(A1;8 ;1);MID(A1;8 ;1)=MID(A1;9 ;1));AND(MID(A1;8 ;1)=MID(A1;9 ;1);MID(A1;9 ;1)=MID(A1;10;1));AND(MID(A1;9 ;1)=MID(A1;10;1);MID(A1;10;1)=MID(A1;11;1));AND(MID(A1;10;1)=MID(A1;11;1);MID(A1;11;1)=MID(A1;12;1));AND(MID(A1;11;1)=MID(A1;12;1);MID(A1;12;1)=MID(A1;13;1));AND(MID(A1;12;1)=MID(A1;13;1);MID(A1;13;1)=MID(A1;14;1));AND(MID(A1;13;1)=MID(A1;14;1);MID(A1;14;1)=MID(A1;15;1))))
```

The idea is to have a rule that compares 1st, 2nd and 3rd character, then another rule that compares 2nd, 3rd, 4th, then another rule for 3rd, 4th, 5th, and so on and so forth. You join this rules with an `OR`, since if any of those match, it means that at some place some repetition exists. Finally, you negate the whole expresion with a `NOT`

Than you can check that both your regex and that column are valid.

Comment: Can you please explain why? What kind of limittions do you have on your goolge sheet?

Answer (score -2):

Donno with which script language you're using
If's in PHP code form,I'd be using `Filter_var($param1, FILTER_VALIDATE..., FILTER_FLAG..)` if i were in your shoes .
It makes your way into both **validating** n **sanitizing** your snippet.
**PEACE**.